# Evergreen + jasmine-jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I want to make use of the new json fixtures ability of jasmine-jquery, but can't get it to work. I have a Rails 3.2 app with evergreen for JS testing. As the readme of https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery said, putting the `jasmine-jquery.js` inside the `spec/javascripts/helpers` dir would load `jasmine-jquery` automatically.

> I put jasmine-jquery (and other libraries like jasmine-ajax) into
>   spec/javascripts/helpers dir (so they are automatically loaded) and
>   fixtures into spec/javascripts/fixtures dir.

But it doesn't. I tried to load the file inside the `spec_helper.js`, but the `require` only points to the public dir.

I also found this answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-evergreen/0Tma5RKqZB8
But the solutions aren't working in my case.

So, where can I tell evergreen / jasmine to load the `jasmine-jquery.js` file, so that I can use the loadFixtures methods...?